# old metadata in search results for PDF

Tags: metadata

Last year, we published our new journal online, but results in Google search show a 2008 date which we cannot trace down to the source. The document was created only recently. The old date makes us look old. Can you please help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhYjO.jpg)

the document in question is available at https://www.globalaccesspartners.org/1907-06_GAP_Journal_BESS_WEB_FA.pdf

many thanks!